# how to fit train CNN with the appropriate input shape?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN and LSTM network with S&P 500 dataset. This is the shape of my train dataset:

> xtrain shape: (6445, 16)
> ytrain shape: (6445,)

this is the input shape I have gave to CNN:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None,16)))
```

withe input shape parameter shown in the code I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_8 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 16]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2.`

Keras expects three-dimensional arrays when working with Conv1D: the expected shape is `[batch_size, sequence_length, feature_dimension]`. In your case, you only have one feature dimension, I suspect the price, but imagine you also wanted to pass the trading volumes data, you would have `xtrain.shape == (6445,16,2)`. The last dimension would contain information about the price and the volume.

To solve your issue, you need to reshape your `xtrain` to

```
(batch_size, sequence_length, feature_dimension=(6445,16,1)
```

To do so, you can use tensorflow:

```py
xtrain = tf.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1) # -1 means expand the LAST axis
```

or with numpy:

```py
xtrain = np.expand_dims(xtrain, axis=-1) # -1 means expand the LAST axis
```

This function just does what the name implies: it adds a new axis in the position specified by `axis`. This results in `xtrain` having the shape we wanted, now you can just proceed with your model, for example:

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None,16,1)))
```